# Display image from Dropbox to a webpage

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

So, I am trying to display an image on my web application. I am getting this image from a Dropbox folder. I want to get a URL I could use to show the image in HTML using the `src` attribute.

I have written this code:

```js
function downloadFile() {
  var Dropbox = require('dropbox').Dropbox;
  var ACCESS_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXX"; // Here the access token key
  var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });

  dbx.filesDownload({ path: '/desiredImg.jpg' })
    .then(function(response) {
      var results = document.getElementById('results');
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.fileBlob);
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.fileBlob);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  return false;
}
```

### Result

[image: I am having this result:]

### Error

[image: but I am also having this error:]

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Discuss-Dropbox-Developer-API/Display-image-from-Dropbox-to-a-webpage/m-p/523223#M1905 ]

Comment: @user29 A bit unrelated to the original question but very important. I think it is not a good idea to use your dropbox api access token in the frontend. It should be used in the backend.

Comment: @MuhammadKamal thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  error was from the `img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.fileBlob);`
It has to be : `img.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(response.result.fileBlob);`